# Using Lightning input file

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, attachment, files, lightninginput

I've been using the lightning:input type="file"

```
<lightning:input type="file" label="Attachment" name="file" multiple="true" accept=".docx, .doc, .xlsx, .zip" onchange="{! c.handleFilesChange }"/>
```

and have this code in the helper

```
handleFilesChange : function(component, event)
{
    var uploadFile = event.getSource().get("v.files")[0];
}
```

Do i need something else so that I can store the file in the Attachments object? I'm new using this input type="file"

Comment: [How to Build a Lightning File Uploader Component](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/05/build-lightning-file-uploader-component.html)

Comment: Also you can use the old but excellent article of @Peter Knolle: [http://peterknolle.com/file-upload-lightning-component/](http://peterknolle.com/file-upload-lightning-component/)

Comment: input file is still beta, I had issues using this component too. The file path after upload was coming back blank, I ented up using @peterknolle's upload file approach in lighting.